# Python Convert to %Y-%m-%d %H:%M With Different Length Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strptime

I want to convert a string in one of the possible formats (%d.%m.%Y %H:%M OR %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S OR %d.%m.%Y) to %Y-%m-%d %H:%M

At present i am using the following code:

```
newMessageDate = log.get('messageDate')
        try:
            newMessageDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(newMessageDate,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        except ValueError:
            newMessageDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(newMessageDate,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

It works fine if the String is in either %d.%m.%Y %H:%M OR %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S but I'm not sure how to add the 3rd format. I tried adding it as an except but it never gets triggered.

Am I on the right track or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Cant you check the length of the "newMessageDate" as a string to determine which format to convert to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a list of possible formats and try them one by one.

```
date_formats = ["%d.%m.%Y %H:%M", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", "%d.%m.%Y", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"]
for date_fmt in date_formats:
    try:
        newMessageDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(newMessageDate, date_fmt).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this be checking length of string and using corresponding formatting from the three,

```
if len(newMessageDate)==15:
    newMessageDate = alpha
elseif len(newMessageDate)==13:
    newMessageDate = beta
elseif len(newMessageDate)==10:
    newMessageDate = gamma
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: To future proof my script, would this be the best way in the case of dates coming through in different lengths? i.e would I add extra Else statements to cope or is there a better way to increase performance of the script?